# Seleccionar Rand() entre From GroupBy y con OrderBy

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos:

- id
- código
- categoría
- venta_web
- marca

Quiero mostrar en laravel sólo código aleatorio y agruparlo por categoría pero que el código se genere aleatoriamente.

El problema es el siguiente: ¿cómo hago para agrupar la categoría y traer un código aleatorio agrupando la categoría?

Tengo el query de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT codigo,categoria
FROM `vcomp_productos_web1`
WHERE venta_web = "SI" AND marca = "VERA"
GROUP BY categoria
ORDER BY rand()
```

Pero me muestra la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para que se genere aleatoriamente el código? he consultado y se hace con `Rand(codigo)` siempre se escoge el primer código y necesito cuaquier código, pero no encuentro la solución.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Mysql

Comment: no logro entender igualmente ahora que lo leo mejor lo que queres hacer, esa columna codigo ya esta completa con datos? vos queres agrupar por categoria, pero que el codigo que se muestra al agrupar cambie, o sea, que no tire siempre el mismo, en base los codigos que ya estan cargados en la tabla para esas categorias?

Comment: Buenos Días si eso es lo que necesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo deberías poder realizar de la siguiente manera:

la query que necesitas es ésta:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT codigo,categoria FROM 'vcomp_productos_web1'
   WHERE venta_web = "SI" AND marca = "VERA"
   ORDER BY rand()
) as sub GROUP BY categoria
```

Para lograrlo con laravel, podrias probar esto:

```
$sub = DB::table('vcomp_productos_web1')
       ->select("codigo, categoria")
       ->where("venta_web","SI")
       ->where("marca", "VERA")
       ->inRandomOrder();

$result = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
    ->mergeBindings($sub) //$sub->getQuery() si $sub es Eloquent
    ->groupBy("categoria")
    ->get();
```

Habría que probarlo, pero debería funcionar.

Comment: Order By rand() funciona en que sql?

Comment: Gracias Leonardo cuando ejecuto el query en Mysql me funciona correctamente estoy haciendo con laravel, Saludos.

Comment: De nada Devin, si el código que te pase te funciona, marca la respuesta como valida también, Saludos!