# Como hacer Rand() entre From GroupBy y con OrderBy

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos

*id *código *categoría *venta_web *marca
Quiero mostrar en laravel solo codigo aleatorio y agruparlo por categoria pero que el codigo se genere aleatoriamente, El problema es el siguiente como hago para agrupar la categoria y traer un codigo aleatorio agrupando la categoria. tengo el query de la siguiente manera

SELECT codigo,categoria FROM vcomp_productos_web1 WHERE venta_web = "SI" AND marca = "VERA" GROUP BY categoria ORDER BY rand()

Pero me muestra la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para que se genere aleatoriamente el código, he consultado y se hace con Rand(codigo) siempre se escoge el primer codigo y necesito cuaquier codigo, pero no encuentro la solución?

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: que version de laravel estas usando?

Comment: Hola estoy utilizando laravel 5.2

Comment: no logro entender igualmente ahora que lo leo mejor lo que queres hacer, esa columna codigo ya esta completa con datos? vos queres agrupar por categoria, pero que el codigo que se muestra al agrupar cambie, o sea, que no tire siempre el mismo, en base los codigos que ya estan cargados en la tabla para esas categorias?

Comment: Devin, por favor, no preguntes lo mismo si pasado un tiempo nadie te ha respondido. Vamos a cerrar esta pregunta por ser un duplicado de la que escribiste anoche: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125720/seleccionar-rand-entre-from-groupby-y-con-orderby